# Outlook interop using system account

Tags: c#, .net, interop, outlook, office-interop

We're trying to use .NET Outlook automation in windows service. It is running under system account.

When trying to call `outlook.CreateItemFromTemplate()` or `outlook.Session.OpenSharedItem()` (here `outlook` is an instance of Outlook application) it fails with exception "Operation aborted (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004004 (E_ABORT))".

Service has "*Allow service to interact with desktop*" option enabled.

This code works just fine when called from usual Win32 application, but not in service running under system account. Does anybody have any suggestions/workarounds how to make it work under system account?